# invisible file on external storage of android device from nautilus

Tags: android, ubuntu, storage, visible, invisible

I'm sorry to take your time, so I'll try to make it short. Before all, I apologize if my English is wrong or if I'm making dumb mistake, English is not my mother tong.  I'm sorry if the answer is silly I'm still not experimented with the making of android apps.
 I'm making a android application and I'm trying to store some files on a public folder on the external storage. I'm having an issue and I have no idea what might be happening.
The issue is so : 
I have a file in the 'download' directory. Then I'm moving the file to my public folder, then I rename it (all this through code). Everything seems to happens fine, the file is correctly moved, is readable and writeable. The file is then visible through app like 'File commander'. Although, when I connect my phone with my computer the file is nowhere to be seen with nautilus (ubuntu folder app), even with the terminal (sudo ls -a doesn't change a thing).

```
String path = (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("myAppFolder").getAbsolutePath() + "/inside_folder/" + fileToMove.getName())
File folder = new File(path);
folder.mkdir();
File thatFile = new File (folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/downloading");
if (thatFile.exist()) thatFile.delete();
try {
   FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(fileToMove);
   FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(thatFile);
   FileChannel inChannel = instream.getChannel();
   FileChannel outChannel = outstream.getChannel();
   inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
   instream.close();
   outstream.close();
   outChannel.close();
   inChannel.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
}
thatFile.renameTo(new File(folder.getAbsolutePath + "/coucou"));
```

For some reason, if the file is rename with 'file commander', the file will now be visible through nautilus. Also, if no other file than the one invisible named 'coucou' then, I will have no way to explore to myAppFolder/inside_folder/imafile/coucou , myAppFolder (and so inside_folder) being unreachable. How can I change that ? How can I make it visible without File Commander. Also, I wonder how can a file be invisible ... anyway thank you for your time and help :-).

edit: Rebooting the device clear the issue. Yet, if new file are created, the won't appear until new reboot (or for now it seems so). I don't want the user to do so each time. Does anyone know how to fix that ? Thank you :).